# Exporting data from GCP Cloud Shell

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

I want to export the data from GCP Cloud Shell.

I mean after running the query on cloud Shell how can I export the data?

Once we have above answer I also what to know if can export the data to Buckets or to local drive on my laptop.

If I Can export the data to local drive or any bucket?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8bjs.png)

Answer (score 2):

Ever noticed that tiny cogwheel icon, top right?

[image: cloudshell screenshot]

Comment: Hi martin,Thanks for your suggestion . it comes with attached screen shot. What location do in need to Give ? I have Mac Laptop. Also does it can save it to Bucket? If yes how Can we do it.     Let me explain fully what i am trying to do. I am trying to run few commands in gcp cloudshell and want to fed the Output data into 3rd Party API tool. hope i am making some sense.

Comment: The image is above  at "enter image description here"

Comment: @Louis one simply cannot interact with an API as you imagine that one could - and I don't have a Mac. while one can pipe whatever output of a command with `somecommand > ./filename.txt`. use `gsutil` for accessing buckets. to use that locally, you have to install the `gcloud` SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can export your file with query to GCS bucket:

```
gsutil cp <your-file-with-query> gs://<your-bucket>
```

To copy to your local drive, you can use the "Download file" option on Cloud Shell options or, given you have `gcloud SDK` installed, execute:

```
gsutil cp gs://<your-bucket>/<your-file-with-query> .
```